# Use Multiple Symbology on single layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, symbology, layers

Task: Display multiple symbologies (Gratuated symbols and Colours) on one layer

Problem: The symbology keeps overwriting itself, so I cannot get both symbologies at the same time

Methods Tried:

1. Export the graduated colour layer as .lyr and import. (Result:Overwrites)
2. Multiple attributes:(Result: Gives me all combinations, and that is not what I want)

I really don`t understand why I cannot get what I want to do in a few simple clicks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, You can add the layer multiple times to the table of contents for each color you wish to display. Set your definition queries for each layer so that only the features you want are shown on your map. Apply the same graduated symbols to each. If you have a large number of colors, this will be a bit intensive.

Comment: Thanks alot. I had to make another data-frame, then copy it, the re-paste it to original data frame, set background to none, and works well.Cheers